# Changing Parameter Type for Delegate Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsinteger, nsuinteger

I have a NSURL delegate method which takes in NSInteger as the parameter

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

NSInteger which is a signed long has a range of -2147483647 to 2147483647. My issue is that sometimes i am getting values which exceed the positive range and this causes the value to go to a negative number which i don't want.

So i changed the NSInteger to NSUInteger

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSUInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSUInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSUInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

My question is whether it is ok to make such a change ? I haven't had any issues so far, the method is being called and i am getting the expected results.

I am concerned about some unforeseen issues that might occur.

Comment: How could you be getting a value that is beyond the range? You really sent over 2GB of data in a single write block?

Comment: totalBytesExpectedToWrite goes over 2 GB sometimes

Comment: Sorry, I didn't scroll enough. I only looked at the `bytesWritten` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to do this. Changing `NSInteger` to `NSUInteger` performs just an ordinary casting. However, I would keep `NSInteger` as a method parameter and then I would cast it explicitly at the beginning of method implementation to `NSUInteger`.